# @html.DisplayFor not displaying data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, view

I have the following view that is giving me problems:

```
@model List<Scheduling_Application.ViewModel.ScheduleMap>
<h2>Map</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="MainTable">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Hour
        </th>
        <th>
            Field 1
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeHour)
        </td>
        <td> 
            <table class="MemberTable">
            @foreach (var member in item.MembersFieldOne)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => member.ID);
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => member.FirstName);
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => member.FirstName);
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Add New", "Create", "Session");
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

My problem is that the @html.displayfor(m => member.FirstName) will not display any data but the TextBoxFor will disply data. The model is set up correctly and is being loaded into the view but why won't the DisplayFor Work?

Comment: This should work fine unless you have some custom version of DisplayFor

Comment: I do not have any custom version of DisplayFor, but I also agree with you it should work, its also why I posted it because to me it should work.

Comment: If you can, please post your Model class code

Comment: I think I have narrowed it down to my CSS page. I finally broke down and looked at the source of the page and the words are there just not showing up. Thank for taking the time to answer but I guess the lesson is to start with simplest answer and work your way back.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to just write your own string template. These (w/ default project settings) will be rendered by using Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MyString) and Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyString), respectively.

Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/String.cshtml

```
@model string
@Model
```

Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml

```
@model string
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x)
```